# Need to get only the first not the whole in the subquery function

Tags: laravel

Please I need help on my Laravel Project. Need only the first item in the subquery function for the left Join of product images...

```
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->select('title', 'price', 'sale_price', 'type', 'name', 'p_image')
    ->leftJoin('product_names', 'products.product_name', 'product_names.id')
    ->leftJoin('product_types', 'products.product_type', 'product_types.id')
    ->leftJoin('product_images', 'products.id', 'product_images.product_id')
    ->leftJoin('product_images', function ($join) {
        // trying to get only the first element from here alone
        $join->on('products.id', 'product_images.product_id');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: why not use `first()` it is in eloquent, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: where should i apply the first() method

Comment: in place of get() use first() will return the first result query, see the link

Comment: @bhucho they want the entire collection, but just want to return 1 row from the join

Comment: @bhuco you are right sire, you are on the line